# Azure Devops Angular Environment Variables

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

At this point, when a commit happens to the Master branch, a build pipeline will generate an artifact based on "ng build --prod", so this artifact uses the production configuration for the project. After that, the artifact will be deployed to the test and production environments.

For the test environment, I want the code to use "environment.dev.ts" and for production "environment.prod.ts". How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use different command for diff build like for prod -> `ng build env=prod --prod` And for test -> `ng build env=test --prod`. Refer this https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-manage-different-environments-with-angular-cli-883c26e99d15

Comment: hi, this won't work. Because I am generating one artifact that I want to deploy to multiple stages. So the best fix is to change the values at runtime, instead of compile time. Using Azure Devops, I could make multiple artifacts though..

Comment: So are you actually using variables from your environment files?

Comment: Yes, for example: API Url.

Comment: Right. So environment files are used only in the build stage (based on the flag). You can’t swap those runtime. You have two options - mulitple build pipelines (with different flags), that way you can keep your current code unchanged or option 2 - use a config.json that contains your environment-dependant variables and load that runtime (means you’d have to change your current code).

Comment: Do you mean, multipe artifacts rather than multiple pipelines? because you can use 1 pipeline to build multiple artifacts I think.

Comment: Yes, either. You can do it in one pipeline and use multiple ng build —flag commands that create separate artifacts. Wouldn’t recommend it though as your buildpipelines will take double the time. A separate pipeline per environment has my preference usually.

Comment: It really depends on your setup. We have commit hooks on a dev branch that triggers a buildpipeline that builds —dev and deploys to dev. A commit to master builds with —prod and deploys the same artifact to both acc and prod.

Comment: There should be only 1 build artifact and many deploys to different environments. Check out https://12factor.net

Comment: @VladimirSerykh But that feels hacky to me.. In Angular you have different ways of building the project for different environments, there is a reason they made it like that right.. so instead of using that approach, you want me to change those variables at runtime?

Comment: If there is a way of doing something, it doesn't mean that you should do it, neither that it is a right way.

Comment: @M Yil did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 26):

There are many ways. I am doing it using "Tokens"
My production environment looks like this

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  host: 'https://#{{FLYMARK_MAIN_DOMAIN}}#',
  stripeKey: '#{{STRIPE_KEY}}'
};
```

So when I build my version is not usable because instead of variables i have tokens.

Then when I do release I do have step to replace tokens. this need to run before you deploy scripts (just modify to your needs)

```
steps:
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@2
  displayName: 'Replace tokens in **/Scripts/widgets/**/*.js'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '**/Scripts/widgets/**/*.js'
    actionOnMissing: fail
    tokenPrefix: '#{{'
    tokenSuffix: '}}#'
```

This task will find my release variables like FLYMARK_MAIN_DOMAIN, STRIPE_KEY and replace in my js files.

[image]

Main benefit is that you build once and can deploy to anywhere just need to replace tokens

PS. Lets say you have dev, staging, prod. Now To dev you deploy after build which is triggered by new push to master, to staging you release when its approved (azure pipeline support that)
[image]

So now lets say you have in dev version 100, you decided to push it into staging and your team start testing. After 3 days your development team pushed to master lots of new stuff so on dev you have version 123, but in staging you still have version 100. After team tested in staging you will push same version to production because you are confident, if you will use separate builds for environment when you are ready to deploy to production you have lots of new stuff in master and maybe you are not confident to push it to production. Again each case is different and there is many ways to do it, I just like this way of doing because it suits my projects.

Comment: I find this hard to understand, I want a simple solution, is there any? I mean, everyone will run against this problem right? What about multiple build pipelines?

Comment: What is hard to understand? And what about multiple build pipelines? Are you familiar how azure releases works?

Comment: Well, I mean, multiple builds based for each environment.

Comment: I always have one build as part of that build i will have angular app as an artifact, then I will have release which deploy to multiple environments. I dont like idea to build per environment its not error safe, if we tested in dev, then same version (just different variables) should be pushed to next stage.

Comment: I understand, so you advise to use a run-time solution?

Comment: @MYil I dont think its runtime, the trick is that when angular compiles its just js scripts, and replace is doing main trick. So after replace I can deploy version with correct replaced values, also see my update with image you can configure environment variables per each environment

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I am facing an issue, that the tokenizer is replacing some unicodes of moment.js and which is causing issue  in loading in IE. You faced any issue like that?

Comment: @j1s it depends which tokens you decided to use. So its all good for me. Plus I am also using moment js

Comment: For those who (like me) didn't immediately understand where this task comes from: this is actually a DevOps extension.  For more information see: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Answer (score 3):

My organization does not allow installing third-party extensions on DevOps. Therefore the top-voted answer was a no go. So I took a different approach. In the build pipelines, I created two build artifacts: one for QA, one for PROD. Different environment files were used in those build steps (Ex: `ng build --c qa`). Both were using `production:true`.

[image]

Then I published both of them to be consumed from the release pipelines. In the QA stage, I deployed the QA build to test servers.

[image]

Once testing has passed and signed off to be promoted to PROD, I could simply use the Azure DevOps approval workflow. When it is promoted to PROD stage, I used the PROD build for deployment.

[image]

I know, I'm not using the same build which got QA verified when deploying to PROD. But at least those builds were created on the same agent, almost at the same time so I guess that is an acceptable compromise.

Even if you use the tokenizer as the other answer suggests, you still end up with somewhat tampered artifact IMO. But then again that is something you have to live with, given that Angular needs to bake its config in. So when it comes to deployments, you will always be promoting a conceptually 'impure' artifact across your environments, one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your azure repo as the artifacts to your release pipeline and then move your build pipeline tasks to the test and prod stages in release pipeline to build and deploy your app respectively. Check below steps.

> 1, Go the release pipeline edit page and click **Add** in **Artifacts** part, TO add your azure repo to the release pipeline as artifacts

[image]

> 2, Click **Continuous deployment trigger** in **Artifacts** part to enable Continuous deployment trigger and set the branch filter.

[image]

> 3, Create stage Test and stage Prod.

[image]

> 4, Copy your build pipeline tasks to Prod stage. And run `ng build env=prod --prod` to build your app. And then deploy your app to prod environment.

.

> 5,Copy your build pipeline tasks to Test stage. And run `ng build env=test --prod` to build your app. And then deploy your app to test environment.

Hope above helps.

Comment: Hi @M Yil Did you try out above steps. How did it going? Please let me know if there is any question.

Comment: Build should happen in the build stage, not release stage. The whole issue here is setting release-time settings (for example secrets and keys) that vary between environments.

Comment: This answer works for me. Not sure why anyone would want to install 3rd party anything if you don't have to. ng build --configuration development, ngbuild --configuration production. Nice and easy as it should be.

Answer (score -1):

I did this in a similar way to @Ε Г И І И О but wanted to add the below. I used parameters in my pipeline to easily create the two artifacts:

https://gist.github.com/davewilton/ca800b406659fb7f55ba531ef433fa1e

[image]

And then I could use the two results in my prod and staging releases.

[image]