# Version stamping of angular app on multiple build environment

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement app version on my angular 8 app. Currently I am using four environment.In each environment I m using AWS code pipeline to deploy my code as well as in each environment inside pipe line i am running ng build .
Due to run of ng build in each environment I am facing issue to manage my app version.
Is there any to manage version stamping of my app.
For each environment my environment specific jenkins job run ng build and put build on S3 bucket.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a Build Number or Timestamp at build time in AngularCLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733660/how-to-insert-a-build-number-or-timestamp-at-build-time-in-angularcli)

Comment: Then similar to this but azure version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249434/azure-devops-angular-environment-variables/59249554#59249554

Comment: I think it's not what he is looking for, because he wants to put the version when only it's passed the code build on AWS pipeline.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-release, i think this can be helpful

Comment: main issue is I am running ng build on each environment.

Comment: when do you want to upgrade your version?

Comment: But thats a point why do you need to build per environment. Idea is to build once then deploy to environment

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat, that sounds right, it can be released with one`ng build` and distributed to 4 envs, right?

Comment: @yash correct. Benefit of this you build and deploy to test. Your team test this version, then you promote same built version to staging then production.

Comment: awesome @VolodymyrBilyachat, why dont you add it as an answer? :)

Comment: Because if you build per environemnt imaging you deployed to test, your team tested, during that time some library released new minor version and its allowed in your package.json. Then you run npm i, ng build and now its different version since it contains new version of librarry

Comment: @yash I already answered that in two places, and posted links here. No reason to keep duplicates ;)

Comment: wow those were your answers :D

Comment: @yash I just wnat to update in prod but it must reflect in other env too.